# How to deal with async functions and collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

Let's assume we have a function `foo(item, callback)` and a collection `items`.

What I'd like to do is substitute every item in `items` with the value returned by the execution of `foo` on it, like `Array.map()` does.

But here comes the problem: the result of `foo` is yielded in the callback, so I have no access to it outside the callback itself (obviously I can't change `foo` to meet my needs).

You could try an approach like

```js
var results = [];
items.map((function(el) {
    foo(el, function(result) {results.push(time)});
});
```

But then you can't know when your `results` collection will be "ready".

I'm totally clueless. **What should I do? What is the pattern?**

*EDIT: I'm more interested in Vanilla Javascript ways of achieve this than tools/libraries, that are anyway acceptable answers.*

Comment: The example provided is not async. The execution of your script will continue after items.map is completed, and immediately after items.map is completed, your results variable will be "ready".

Comment: Why? The callback of `foo` function can be executed at any time.

Comment: wrap your code in function and use callbacks....

Comment: After I written a lengthy comment explaining why foo is not called async, now I saw that you are referring to the callback provided to the foo function, not to the call of foo itself. Sorry, my bad. I'm thinking and I'll come with an answer.

Comment: @Ravi please could you motivate your statement? How can I access `results` being sure it contains all the values I need?
Even if I wrap that snippet in another callback I can't get rid off the uncertainity on `results` state.

Comment: Here's the [little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coder_raaaz/apkfvjd9/) i made, to clarify your doubt,

Comment: @Ravi Adding a `setTimeout` to your callback to replicate an async call and [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/apkfvjd9/1/) breaks. Your code only works because your callback is called instantly.

Comment: @Ben I don't see any `setTimeout` in my code. PS. It's Tiborg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla JS I'd do it like this:

```
var items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']

function foo(item, callback) {
    // this is provided just to test the async nature of your callback
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback.call(null, item + ' async')
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
}


var results = [];
var count = 0;
items.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    foo(element, function (result) {
        results[index] = result;

        // the actual "ready" check
        if (++count == items.length) {
            // here you should notify your code that all items have been replaced

            // after a random number of seconds between 1 and 5 in the current example, it should
            // write ['item 1 async', 'item 2 async', 'item 3 async']
            console.log(results);
        }
    })
});
```

I don't know if this is a pattern or the best way, but I think is simple and fast. Be aware that forEach works only in IE9+. For IE < 9 you could either use the jQuery .each or manually write a for loop (but be careful with closures and indices).

Answer (score 2):

This becomes pretty trivial when using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

```
async.each(items, function(el, callback) {
    foo(el, function(result) {
        callback(result);
    });
}, function(results) {
    doSomethingWith(results); //results being an array of the callbacked results.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! That's actually a great library. But can you explain how it works? I tried to look at the source code of `async.each`, yet I can't really understand what's going on, I think because the entire code it's a bit hacky.

Comment: It's not hacky. It will count the items in the collection and increment a number when the callback is received. If the incremented number is the same as the item count then it will return the results.

Comment: Oh I suspected it,  very clever, yet it still sounds hacky to me